# Spring Security how to get username from PasswordEncoder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

When adding a new user, I save his password in the database, in the form of SHA256 (cleartext_password + salt). The salt value  I save next to it in a separate column for each user. Accordingly, the password check should be performed as follows: we extract the password cleartext from the BasicAuth header, get the salt value for this user from the database, execute SHA256 (cleartext_password + salt) and check that the resulting string and the passwored stored in the database matches. In order to implement this, I to create a custom PasswordEncoder which will perform verification, but I can't access username from PasswordEncoder. I need username to get salt for this user and execute verifcation. How can I get out of this situation?

Here's the current implementation of Security:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new CustomPasswordEncoder());
    }

}

@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
        if (user != null) {
            return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.
                    User.withUsername(username)
                    .password(new CustomPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()))
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

public class CustomPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return rawPassword.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        String sha256hex = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(rawPassword.toString()); // Here should be DigestUtils.sha256Hex(rawPassword.toString() + salt)
        return sha256hex.equals(encodedPassword);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a custom AuthenticationProvider? SO that way you can Override public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) and would be able to get username by String userName = authentication.getName(); and password by String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

Comment: Please be aware that storing the passwords in that way is no longer secure. You can learn more about why, as well as a better approach in the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-history).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement and solved this problem by using Java thread local variables. Probably it looks ugly but I did not have much time back then and it worked for me. This is my thread local declaration

```
    public class MySecurityContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> usernameTL = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setUsername(String username) {
        usernameTL.set(username);
    }

    public static String getUsername() {
        return usernameTL.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        usernameTL.remove();
    }
```

}

Then I define my UserDetailsService bean where I have the username and can place it in the thread local variable

```
    @Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository){
    return username -> {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            MySecurityContext.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            return user;
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found");
    };
}
```

And finally I have my custom password encoder where I extract the thread variable value

```
public class DatabasePasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private String salt;

public DatabasePasswordEncoder(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, String salt){
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    this.salt = salt;
}

@Override
public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
    String username = MySecurityContext.getUsername();
    String passwordString = username + salt + rawPassword.toString();
    MySecurityContext.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

A clever trick to solve this is to load the user first in your `/authenticate` method

encrypt the password into the form it was stored in the database and then use a `NoOpPasswordEncoder` to compare.

---

Ensure you include the salt with your own `CustomUserDetails` impl

---

Within your `/authenticate` method
Call

`final  CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(auth.getUsername());`

---

Extract your salt and then create an encoded password from the normal password the user provided

`String encodedPassword = encode(auth.getPassword, userDetails.getSalt());`

---

then pass the encodedPassword to the authenticate method

`authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, encodedPassword ));`